# Prevent Save Action on Error in WFFM Forms

Tags: wffm

I have three save actions on a WFFM form. If some error occurs in first save action then i don't want other two save actions to be executed. Can anyone please suggest how i can achieve that.

Comment: What sitecore version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following in **9.1**:

On the FormSubmitContext class, you can use the Canceled property to check to see if you should do some work. If you have run into a case where you don't want your processing to continue, you can use the Abort() method, which will set Canceled to true.

```
    public class MySubmitAction : SubmitActionBase<MyModelData>
    {
        public MySubmitAction(ISubmitActionData submitActionData) : base(submitActionData)
        {
        }

        protected override bool Execute(MyModelData data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
        {
            if (formSubmitContext.Canceled)
                return false;
            bool somethingWrong = false;
            // Do some work here.....

            if(somethingWrong)
            {
                formSubmitContext.Abort();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```